# Multiple comparison of string variable in perl

Tags: string, perl, variables, comparison

I'm trying make some kind of bash-like case statement in perl by using only if operator.

```
my $var = shift @ARGV;
print "err\n" if (!$var || ($var ne "one") || ($var ne "two"));
```

The problem is, that 'if' statement does not work as expected. For example, if I pass as input 'one' or 'two' it prints 'err', but, if I swap 'ne' with 'eq' script works correctly.

perl version 5.16.3 linux

Comment: Could you make clear what expected behaviour is? Are all true values allowed except `one` and `two`? Or are *only* `one` or `two` allowed?

Comment: The code must return 'err' only if argument is not defined, or is not 'one' or 'two'. Otherwise no output at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on [De Morgan’s laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

```
not($p && $q) == (!$p || !$q)
not($p || $q) == (!$p && !$q)
```

If the only allowed values are `"one"` or `"two"`, then you could write:

```
print "err\n"
  unless defined $var
     and $var eq "one" || $var eq "two";
```

If you want to use `ne`, then:

```
print "err\n"
  if ! defined $var
  or $var ne "one" && $var ne "two";
```

These two forms are equivalent. If you have more than two allowed strings, it gets much easier and more efficient by using a hash:

```
my %allowed;
@allowed{"one", "two"} = ();

print "err\n" unless defined $var and exists $allowed{$var};
```

---

The problem with your code was: When or-ing multiple conditions together, it is sufficient for any one sub-condition to be true for the whole condition to be true.

Given an `undef` or other false value, `!$var` is true.
Given the string `"one"`, the `$var ne "two"` is true.
Given any other string, the `$var ne "one"` is true.

Therefore, `($var ne "one") || ($var ne "two")` is always true.